# python: define Hotkey that modifies the last command?

Tags: python, hotkeys

i wonder if i can define a (let me call it) macro in python that allows me to modify the last command in a specific, scripted way by pressing something (easy and definable) like crtl+[key]. For example, putting the left hand side of the assignment of the previous (or last) assignment into the len() function:

```
>>>str='some string'
[invoking my macro with crtl+[key]]
>>>len(str)
11
```

beware, hobby (=nonprofessional) programmer here ;)
i use the Spyder environment of Anaconda